# Azure Antimalware Scheduling? How to Change?

Tags: azure

I installed MS Antimalware on an Azure Windows 2016 VM.  I did some settings and mistakenly set it up to do a full scan every day.

All I want to do is change this to a a daily quick scan.

I'm aghast how difficult something so minor is to change.  How in the world do I change this?  Security Center doesn't list antimalware anyone since it's installed.  And the VM itself doesn't show any settings for it.

This is maddening.

Comment: I've done countless google searches, all that comes up is learn.microsoft.com showcasing the service.  Nothing usable for reconfiguring it.

Comment: So I checked gpedit thinking it might be setup there = nope.  nothing is configured.  I have zero idea even where the command is coming from to do the scans.

Comment: Do you try to uninstall this extension and try to install it again?

Comment: I found it under the extensions of the VM.  I re-installed, which canceled the full-scans thankfully, but now it isn't doing the quick scan like how I set it up.